# Use first value of an array generated by a ms_sql query in a if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Ok, so basically I have a query that returns an array, and then it gets looped:

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Segments ORDER BY Squares");

    if (!$result) {
    echo 'query failed';
    exit;

              }

        while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $txtsquares = $row["Squares"];
    echo $txtsquares;
```

When echoed the variable $txtsquares is equal to an array value, for example lets say 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8.

I need this array/loop. But I would like to grab the first value of this array and use it in an if statement, like so:

```
value="<?php echo $txtsquares; ?>"
<?php if ($txtsquares == 1) { ?> checked="checked" <?php }
else{ ?> checked="" <?php } ?>/>
```

However obviously this is wrong, because the value will never equal 1 because its an array. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? I am new at PHP so sorry if it is an easy question, I have Googled it but without much luck.

Comment: Use PDO over `mssql_*`.  At the very least you should probably use `sqlsrv_*`.

Comment: Is `txtsquares` actually an array, or is it a string with space-separated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use the first element of `$txtsquares` try this:

```
value="<?php echo $txtsquares; ?>"
<?php if ($txtsquares[0] == 1) { ?> checked="checked" <?php }
else{ ?> checked="" <?php } ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$txtsquares` is a string of numbers, and you **know** it's a string of numbers... you could do something like this:

```
$txtsquares = "1234";

$str_values = str_split($txtsquares);
// array('1', '2', '3', '4')

$int_values = array_map(function($i) { return (int)$i; }, $str_values);
// array(1, 2, 3, 4)

$first_value = $int_values[0];
```